# Error while creating a new command in a custom package

Tags: packages, package-writing

I'm trying to follow the steps in [this link](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Writing_your_own_package) to create a new package. My current code is

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{custom}[2022/10/29 LaTeX custom]
\let\a\alpha
\newcommand{\bfit}[1]{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}
```

I include the package above into a .tex file with the following code:

```
The following is a test that the \bfit{custom} package is working properly: $\a$.
```

I get the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.38 The following is a test that the \bfit
                                       {custom} package is working pr...

?
```

Removing `\bfit` from the sentence allows me to compile the .tex (note that `\a` *is* defined).

---

Howcome `\a`is defined while `\bfit` isn't? How can I fix the above so as to have them both defined.

Comment: If i insert your definitions in standard `article` document, they work fine. Do please extend your code fragments to complete small document, which reproduce your problem.

Comment: Don't use \let unless you know exactly what you are doing. If \a is already defined you would be overwriting it without warning.

Comment: redefining `\a` will break latex accents.  You have provided no code that shows the error you are asking about